# Multiple python Tkinter files to be combined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have 3 python files, one containing the code of a scientific calculator, one with the programming calculator, and one with the simple calculator. I have not used any classes. I want to make it such that when I open the basic calculator, it has options to take me to the programming or scientific calculator alongside closing current window, and this should happen in all the three calculators. how can I do that?

Comment: This is great! You can do that with a little bit of effort and refactoring!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque how do i go about it?

Comment: You can probably use the `os` module and the `subprocess` module to run a command `python other_calculator.py` and then the other_calculator will open, the previous running program can then be terminated. This is one approach I can think of.